# run Laravel Task Scheduling on hPane (Hostinger - Cron Job)

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduler

as [Running The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) says I must run this Command:

```
* * * * * cd /home/u285707107/domains/dmn.com/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but in hPanel Cron Job-s I can't use special characters, so I create **cron.sh** file as [they say](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/5646919-how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-with-special-characters-at-hostinger)

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/u285707107/domains/dmn.com/ && php artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and in Hostinger Cron Job I run Command:

```
/bin/sh /home/u00000000/domains/dmn.com/public_html/dmn/app/Console/cron.sh
```

but it don't works : ( (

My **Kernel.php** file is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Models\Proview;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
        $schedule->call(function () {
            Proview::query()->update(['today' => 0]);
        })->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands(){
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

can someone Help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need bash file for this, just create a php script file (.php) and set the cron job using the type "php"

the script should be :

```
<?php
chdir('/path-to-your-project'); // cd /path-to-your-project
exec('php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1'); // execute php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 in powershell
```

for the cron job

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the below scripts with yours.

**cron.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/u285707107/domains/dmn.com && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Hostinger Cron Job**

```
* * * * *   /bin/sh /home/u285707107/domains/dmn.com/public_html/dmn/app/Console/cron.sh
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).